# How do you validate a window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
def createWidgets(self):
        self.INSTRUCTIONS = Button(self) #creating button linked to instructions_window
        self.INSTRUCTIONS["text"] = "Instructions"
        self.INSTRUCTIONS["fg"]   = "green"
        self.INSTRUCTIONS["command"] =  self.instruction_window #command which opens instructions_window

        self.INSTRUCTIONS.pack({"side": "left"})
```

Currently, if I press the button multiple times then the instructions window will open multiple times. How do I ensure that when the button is pressed, if the window is already open then it will flash to show that the same window can't be opened. Is there a command? Or do I need to use a validation of some sort?

Comment: when you say "instructions window" are you talking about a popup window, or a region in the current window that displays text?

Comment: Yes, a new pop up window. Also, further into the program I will be needing to do this for the window for each question and also the yes/no/enter buttons in each question to ensure the function is only called once and not 1 million times - any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a great article dealing with more complicated examples of dialog boxes.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Essentially what you are looking for is almost like a [modal dialog window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) except it seems with the additional ability to still interact with the parent window to a degree. At this point it may be worth considering making it totally modal, but I do not know your use case. If not, you can definitely adapt the scripts given on the tutorial website to fit your needs.

Comment: a modal dialog box "with the additional ability to still interact with the parent window" isn't a modal dialog box. The very definition of modal means you can't interact with other windows.

Comment: That's why I said almost... because he wants to disable at least some functionality of the parent. At least to me, that's a hint that it *should* be totally modal (maybe OP has never heard of them) - but once again I don't know the specific use case. Regardless, it then becomes as simple as removing the `grab_set()` method and replacing it with a method to disable the parent window's button.

Comment: I think if it's a floating, non-modal window, instead of disabling the button, the button should raise the window in case it got hidden behind the main window. Otherwise the user might forget it was opened, and be wondering why the button is disabled.

Comment: True that - misread that part in OP's question. Now if only OP would get back to us...

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to create a function that will create the window if it doesn't exist, and then display the window. Personally I don't think there's a need to flash the window, but you could do that if you want. Tkinter doesn't know how to flash a window, but you can do something simple like changing the colors briefly.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.instruction_window = None
        self.instructions = tk.Button(self, text="Instructions", foreground="green",
                                      command=self.show_instructions)
        self.instructions.pack(side="left")

    def show_instructions(self):
        '''show the instruction window; create it if it doesn't exist'''
        if self.instruction_window is None or not self.instruction_window.winfo_exists():
            self.instruction_window = InstructionWindow(self)
        else:
            self.instruction_window.flash()

class InstructionWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width=40, height=8)
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.insert("end", "these are the instructions")

    def flash(self):
        '''make the window visible, and make it flash temporarily'''

        # make sure the window is visible, in case it got hidden
        self.lift()
        self.deiconify()

        # blink the colors
        self.after(100, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="black", fg="white"))
        self.after(500, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="white", fg="black"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall let you know how I get on. I am fairly new to Pyhthon and Tkinter and am in High School so don't have the best experience. Just trying to get my head aroun things as my teachers have never used the language either.

Comment: Bryan: if I was to create more classes, say for each of my 10 questions would I need to change the "def __init__(self, parent):" for each one to avoid conflicts? I am not sure about classes as I have no experience of using them. Thanks

Comment: @user3056786: I can't do that question justice in a comment box. In short, you would probably create one class and 10 instances, each with different text. But then you can't quite use the code I posted, since you need to change the text depending on which button was pressed. It's all possible, but that sort of thing needs to be asked in a separate question.

Comment: Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473122/how-to-add-questions-and-a-scoring-system-to-my-quiz